# Is it possible to change order of attachment views to drupal page view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, attachment

I have a view with a page display that contains essentially content A, that content exists in one column.  in addition, I've got another 6 attachment displays that display content B,C,D,E, etc. in another column.

Is it possible to modify the order of the the attached view displays?  Right now i've got them all set to attach after Content A Page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you are asking.

So what I think you are trying to do is have a page with a view, then multiple views attached to the page view and you want to be able to move those attached view around.

### What I recommend

Use this amazing module: '[view block attachment](http://drupal.org/project/views_attachment_block)'
this way your attached view is a block, but yet still an attachment!
its the best of both worlds.

**How to use it in brief:** 
You would create a new 'block attachment view type'.
set what view its attached to, just like you do with attached views now. *then* go to your blocks page and put the attached block in the region you want.

**In context of your question** you could then make 'block attachment view' for B, C, D & E all would be attached to view A, you would then go to the blocks page and move blocks B, C, D & E into the regions you want and they will only be in those regions when you look at view A which they are attached to.

**Use Drupal Module : '[view block attachment](http://drupal.org/project/views_attachment_block)'**

Answer (score 3):

Views 3.x (currently [in alpha](http://drupal.org/node/765092) though it seems stable for me) provides a UI for this.

- Views 3.x displays reorder button:

[image: Views 3.x displays reorder button]

- Views 3.x displays reorder:

[image: Views 3.x displays reorder]

Comment: This should be the answer. So simple, but not that obvious!

Comment: In modern Drupal (8+, so if you are using Drupal 10 or 11 etc) there is a bug where this does not work as expected:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2943293

So, for now, if you want to control the order of attachments, you need to change the machine names of the displays to be the order you want alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

It`s possible at the database level:

```
select * from views_display order by vid,position;
```

and change values at position column.