# Reordering view display added with Views Attach

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'm using **Drupal 6.20**, **Views 2** and [**Views attach**](http://drupal.org/project/views_attach) module to append few view displays to a full node view. Is there some way to reorder the attached views? The views should still be grouped together (ie. I do not want to insert any other CCK field between them), but I want to display them in different order than that they automatically appear in.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this through the GUI as Views Attach just displays the attachments in the order they were created.

You need to export the View to code (open the view, under "Export" tab) and manually move the attachments into the required order. You may need to update the attachment number too (ie. attachment_2 becomes attachment_1).

Re-import the View using "Import" - either under a new name or by deleting the old view before you run Import.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but Views Attach doesn't seem to take order in which view displays where added into consideration as they are displayed. I've added displays in order I wished they would be showed, but they are rendered in random-like order (2, 1, 3). When I export view displays are also ordered in a way I would like them to be visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Views 3.x which offers a UI to reordering displays. I just attached some screenshots at [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612987/is-it-possible-to-change-order-of-attachment-views-to-drupal-page-view/4751371#4751371).

Comment: It looks promising, but I'd prefer not to use alpha version of Views 3 for client's website. Still, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Always evaluate the module on its own merits, not (just) on what the developer says is the version number. That is, sometimes a dev or alpha or beta version of a module works just fine and is stable and does what you need it to do. If it doesn't work for you in a development server, obviously don't use it. But don't reject a module out of hand just because of the version number.